# AnimationDrawable stopping while using direct rendering

Tags: google-gdk

My GDK app is setup exactly like the Compass example app.  I'm using a Renderer which contains a view. The goal here is to create an activity indicator using a .png sequence that I can bring up whenever something is loading.  In the renderer I inflate the layout XML that contains an ImageView for the activity indicator.  Here's how I setup the animation:

```
        progressIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_loader_animation);
        progressAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)progressIndicator.getBackground();

        progressAnimation.setCallback(new Drawable.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
               // Log.i(TAG, "invalidateDrawable");
                return;
            }

            @Override
            public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
                Handler h = new Handler();
                h.postAtTime(what, when);
            }

            @Override
            public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable drawable, Runnable runnable) {
               //Log.i(TAG, "unscheduleDrawable");
                return;
            }


        });
```

When my app needs to display the animation I set the ImageView to VISABLE, and call

```
progressAnimation.start();
```

The problem is that the after a few seconds the animation just stops and I can't start it again.  I'm not exactly sure what causes the animation to stop but I suspect it's b/c of something happening in the View that the renderer contains.  I do have oneshot="false" in the animation-list xml.  How do I prevent my animation from stopping?  How can I even figure out what's stopping it?  Thanks.

**Update:**  Still no clue why this is happening however there are multiple things that cause the animation to stop.  When my app sorts and array of objects, it stops.  When I hit a URL to get JSON, it stops.  If I comment those things out, the animation continues and doesn't stop.  I'm giving up at this point and just making some blinking text to indicate activity.

Comment: When you say the animation runs for a few seconds and then stops, does that mean it's doing one complete cycle and then stopping, or is it more sporadic than that?

Comment: it was hard for me to determine exactly what's stopping it.  It definitely runs for a few cycles before it stops.